# The only sets in $R^n$ which are both open and closed are the empty set and $R^n$ itself.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Proposition : The only sets in $R^n$ which are both open and closed are the empty set and $R^n$ itself.

I came up with the proof of this claim and I'd like to know if my proof is correct.

Proof:

Let $S$ be the nonempty proper subset of $R^n$ which is both open and closed. Then $T = R^n-S$ is also a nonempty proper subset of $R^n$ which is both open and closed. Now take a point $s_0$ in $S$ and $t_0$ in $T$. Then we can consider a closed box $J_1$ which contains both $s_0$ and $t_0$.  The n-dimensional interval $I_1^k$ is defined by the inequalities

$s_k\le x_k \le t_k$ (k=1, 2, $...$, n ), where each $s_k$ and $t_k$ are the k-th coordinates of $s_0$ and $t_0$. Without loss of generality, assume that for all k, $s_k \le t_k$.

Here $J_1$ denotes the catesian product

$J_1$ = $I_1^1$ x  $\cdots$ x $I_n^1$

Now, bisect all of the n 1-dimensional intervals and the point $\frac {s_0+t_0}{2}$ will lie in the center of the bisected box. This point belongs to either $S$ or $T$. Say it belongs to $S$ then, rename it $s_1$ and the original $t_0$ to be $t_1$. Now again consider a box that has both points as vertices like the previous case and repeat the process.

Writing $I_k^m$ = [$s_k^m$,$t_k^m$],

we have  $t_k^m$ - $s_k^m$ = $\frac {t_k-s_k}{2^{m-2}}$

Then for each fixed k, the sup of all left endpoints must therefore be equal to the inf of all right endpoints, and their common value we donote by $b_k$ (actually we know this by Bolzano-Weierstrass).

Now we assert that **b**=($b_1$,$...$,$b_n$) is a limit point of $S$ and $T$. To see this, take any n-ball B(**b**; $r$). The point **b** of course belongs to each of the boxes $J_1$, $J_2$, $...$ constructed above, and when $m$ is such that $max_k\frac {t_k-s_k}{2^{m-2}}$ < r/2, this neighborhood will include $J_m$ and since $J_m$ contains both points of $S$ and $T$, **b** is a limit point of both sets. But since both sets are closed, they both contain **b**, which is a contradiction. Hence, the proposition is true.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo This one is about $\mathbb R^n$, though.

Comment: @HowAboutANiceBigCupOf Fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is almost correct. In the first sentence  of the last paragraph you should replace "is a limit point of" by "belongs to the closure of" (thanks to  Andres Caicedo for the tip).

Also, you did not actually need boxes: you could take a line segment with endpoints in $S$ and $T$, and repeatedly bisect it as in your proof.

Comment: It is not quite correct. The point $\mathbf b$ is in both $A$ and $B$, but it is not necessarily a limit point of both. (Or, at least, the given argument does not show that.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Fixed.